# Javascript program has something wrong ,I don't know why the length of log is not 10?

Tags: javascript

Javascript program has something wrong ,I don't know why the length of log is not 10?
the input s :

```js
const s = "AAAAACCCCCAAAAACCCCCCAAAAAGGGTTT"

var findRepeatedDnaSequences = function(s) {
  var set = new Set()
  var seqSet = new Set()
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length - 11; i++) {
    let sub = s.substr(i, i + 10)
    console.log(sub)
    if (set.has(sub)) {
      seqSet.add(sub)
    } else {
      set.add(sub)
    }
  }
  return Array.from(set)
};

findRepeatedDnaSequences(s)
```

the console result:Javascript program has something wrong ,I don't know why the length of log is not 10?

```
AAAAACCCCC
AAAACCCCCAA
AAACCCCCAAAA
AACCCCCAAAAAC
ACCCCCAAAAACCC
CCCCCAAAAACCCCC
CCCCAAAAACCCCCCA
CCCAAAAACCCCCCAAA
CCAAAAACCCCCCAAAAA
CAAAAACCCCCCAAAAAGG
AAAAACCCCCCAAAAAGGGT
AAAACCCCCCAAAAAGGGTTT
AAACCCCCCAAAAAGGGTTT
AACCCCCCAAAAAGGGTTT
ACCCCCCAAAAAGGGTTT
CCCCCCAAAAAGGGTTT
CCCCCAAAAAGGGTTT
CCCCAAAAAGGGTTT
CCCAAAAAGGGTTT
CCAAAAAGGGTTT
CAAAAAGGGTTT
```

Comment: what does the variable `s` represents?

Comment: Is `s` supposed to be the string at the beginning?

Comment: @connerbrain, substr function takes start and length as args. Then second argument is not the end index. Since you are passing i+10, the returned string length will keep increasing.

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to achieve

Comment: s.length - 11 = 32 - 11 = 21. What do you mean by "length of log is not 10"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments you're giving to `substr()` are appropriate for `substring()`. Since `substr()` is deprecated, you should just change to `substring()` and you'll get the results you want.

```js
const s = "AAAAACCCCCAAAAACCCCCCAAAAAGGGTTT"

var findRepeatedDnaSequences = function(s) {
  var set = new Set()
  var seqSet = new Set()
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length - 11; i++) {
    let sub = s.substring(i, i + 10)
    console.log(sub)
    if (set.has(sub)) {
      seqSet.add(sub)
    } else {
      set.add(sub)
    }
  }
  return Array.from(set)
};

findRepeatedDnaSequences(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) takes a starting offset and a *length*. You should call just `.substr(i, 10)`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const s = "AAAAACCCCCAAAAACCCCCCAAAAAGGGTTT"

var findRepeatedDnaSequences = function(s) {
  var set = new Set()
  var seqSet = new Set()
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length - 11; i++) {
    let sub = s.substr(i,  10)
    console.log(sub)
    if (set.has(sub)) {
      seqSet.add(sub)
    } else {
      set.add(sub)
    }
  }
  return Array.from(set)
};

findRepeatedDnaSequences(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

in js there are 2 functions:
substr():

> The substr() method returns a portion of the string, starting at the
> specified index and extending for a given number of characters
> afterwards.

substring().

> The substring() method returns the part of the string between the
> start and end indexes, or to the end of the string.

you are using the 1st one, and from your question, you are expecting the 2nd.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring.